# Issue list for old version of barcode scanner

Tags: zxing

Due to some reason I am still using old barcode scanner version 4 3.2. in my project currently. In current official site (GitHub) I only can find the version 4.5.1 and it says "This is the latest release before the project migrated to Github." Does any one know how to get the issue list for the version 4.3.2 so that I can assess the issues to determine whether it is worth to upgrade to the new version of barcode scanner.
I think the issue list that I am interested should be available in the old official Zxing site but I am not able to the reach it.

Comment: I'm not sure there would be a fixed issue list, or a way to get a snapshot of GitHub's issues at an old point in time. But you could look at [their CHANGES file](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/CHANGES) to see a summary of what has actually been fixed since 4.3.2.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I checked the change log, but I still need an issue list because change log is too rough for my need.